# Problem with Struct and Pointer in C language

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm newbie. Pointer make my crazy T_T.
Now, I'm do the socket programming project.
This is my code.

```
typedef struct {
        char *ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        char *username[20];
        time_t login_time;
        enum client_state client_state;
        int no_login;
    } Client;

    Client client[max_connections] = {}; // set to null
char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
.
.
.
.
.
if(client[new_fd-4] == NULL) {  // if fist attempt, client always null
   // I want to setting client[new_fd-4].ip = &remoteIP
   // How to write the code ??
}
```

Comment: Start with C basics, pointers are essential in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` does not mean "null", it means "zero-initialized".

You can't put null values into the `client` array because `client` is an array of structs, and structs can't be null. If you want the `client` array to be able to contain "null" values, you need to make it an array of *pointers to structs*, e.g. `Client* client[max_connection] = {};`. This sets all the values in `client` to `NULL` because when talking about pointers, `0` and `NULL` are synonyms. When pointers aren't involved, this is not true because nothing other than a pointer can be null.

Note that since `client` will now contain pointers, you will have to allocate and deallocate the `Client` structs with `malloc` and `free`, e.g.

```
if(client[new_fd-4] == NULL) {  // if fist attempt, client always null
   client[new_fd-4] = malloc(sizeof(Client));
   client[new_fd-4]->no_login = 1; // For example. Note use of -> instead of .
}
```

And when you're done with some element `client[i]`:

```
free(client[i]);
client[i] = NULL; // Not strictly necessary, but a good idea
```

And I really doubt that you want to do this:

```
// I want to setting client[new_fd-4].ip = &remoteIP
```

I think what you really want is to *copy* the data contained in `remoteIP` into the `ip` member, like this:

```
memcpy(client[new_fd-4]->ip, &remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Comment: I have a problem with line " memcpy(client[new_fd-4]->ip, &remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN); ". Compiler warn me " ../src/server.c:362: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast ". After I run, it terminate after execute this line.

Comment: Where you have `char*` as the type for `ip` and `username`, it should just be `char`. You want an array of characters for those members, not an array of character-pointers. I overlooked this mistake initially.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set "char *ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN]; char *username[20];". It works now. But I found new problem, I just memcpy ip but 'ip' and 'username' change. 
IP : ::1
username : ::1

Comment: Sorry, It my mistake again. I forgot to initialize size of IP and username.

Answer (score 1):

Update: `Client client[max_connections] = {};` will create an array of `Client` objects whose all fields are initialized to zeros. So the check should be something like: `if(client[new_fd-4].ip == NULL)`

If `remoteIP` is a static array, or if it's a local array and `client[new_fd - 4]` won't be used after the current function is returned, you can just do:

```
client[new_fd - 4].ip = remoteIP;
```

Otherwise, you should assign memory and do a memcpy.

```
client[new_fd - 4].ip = malloc(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
strncpy(client[new_fd - 4].ip, remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you didn't mean to define the `ip` structure member as an array of `char*`, nor the `username` structure member.

Try:

```
typedef struct {
    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    // ...
 } Client;
```

And in the code:

```
strncpy(client[new_fd-4].ip, remote_ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
```